# Why is this white space appearing below the appbar layout?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, kotlin, android-fragments

I dont know what is causing this with space. It has to be some xml atribute i dont know about. This is a fragment which is fine:
[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:background="@drawable/bg">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logo_home"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="131dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And here is an image of another fragment where the space appears:
[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark">

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug happens to appear when you add to your main activity resource file: fitsSystemWindows = true.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug from the Android team's side.
There's nothing you can do except hope they fix it.
Unless you make it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

As previously answered, this is a bug from Android's side. A solution would be to use the relative layout inside of a linear layout and assign a weight of 10 to the relative layout such that it covers the whole screen:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
    android:weightSum="10">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp">
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```